# How to use android calendar for specif application

Tags: android, calendar

In android from 4.0 ice cream sandwich we can use calendar API from that I need some information how to use the android default calender to insert / view delete the events to mange for inside my specific application.

I mean

1. How need to display the calender inside my application
2. How to list the events based on the date from from database.
3. How add some events

Note:
but this events only specific for my app.. have to display inside my app only.. this events will not be display in the common calender, How can we mange ?? any idea

Answer (score 0):

this code will helpful for your requirement https://github.com/nevalla/CalendarView